# NASM64 "unterminated string"

Tags: string, nasm

In NASM I define a string constant of punctuation marks in the .data section:

```
punctuations: db  '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~''',0
```

The NASM assembler says "warning: unterminated string."  I've tried a number of different ways to write this string, but I keep getting the same error (for example, punctuations: db  "!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~",0).

I think the problem may be that there is a double quote and a single quote within the string, but I'm not sure.  My research hasn't found a correct answer.

Any help on the right way to write this string will be very appreciated.

EDIT:  I removed the single and double quotes from the string and now I do not get that error.  So the problem is the quotes within the string.

Comment: http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html - I don't see any `'''foo'''` string quote syntax .. a triple-quote is a Python-ism. Try with a single ' quote, as shown in the referenced documentation: `'!()-[]{};:\',<>./?@#$%^&*_~',0`

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately punctuations: db  '!()-[]{};:\',<>./?@#$%^&*_~',0 generates the same message (unterminated string)

Comment: However, I removed the single and double quotes from the string and now I do not get that error.  So the problem is the quotes within the string.  See my edit above.

Comment: What about separating it out? `'!()-[]{};:',39,34,'<>./?@#$%^&*_~',0` The documentation doesn't appear explicitly state that escapes are supported in string literals (as opposed to character literals).. however "A string constant looks like a character constant, only longer", and it seems odd as if escapes would only work in one context.

Comment: Yes, that's a great idea (using the ASCII codes) -- and it works !!!  Thanks very much.

Comment: Another option is use backquote character **`** for the string. In NASM (but not YASM which may be a disadvantage). That allows you to use _C_  escape character (backslash). You can read about it in the NASM manual under [Character Strings](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html) .Using the ASCII codes would work in either YASM/NASM. I am just pointing out an option, nothing more.